# TensorFlow Local Training LibCurl Error Code 6 (tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate() error)

Tags: python, tensorflow, libcurl

Running on Ubuntu 16.04, (beginner in Tensorflow). Followed [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-your-own-object-detector-with-tensorflows-object-detector-api-bec72ecfe1d9) step by step-ish:

The article trains the model using Google Cloud Service, but I wanted to do it locally on my computer's graphics card. I got all the files ready, and everything seems fine, but I get the following error.

`2018-08-17 12:51:31.302420: I tensorflow/core/platform/cloud/retrying_utils.cc:77] The operation failed and will be automatically retried in 1.03428 seconds (attempt 1 out of 10), caused by: Unavailable: Error executing an HTTP request: libcurl code 6 meaning 'Couldn't resolve host name', error details: Couldn't resolve host 'metadata'`

Image Below:

[image]

The model_main.py code is [here](https://github.com/Tekunalogy/Fish-Detection).

We have narrowed it down to this line of code in `model_main.py`:

`tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_specs[0])`

Please let me know what you think may be the issue. If you need more info let me know. Thank you.